# django REST ldap authentication with Cassandra

Tags: django, rest, authentication, cassandra, ldap

I am writing a rest api using [django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). I store my data in Cassandra. I am using [django-cassandra-engine](https://r4fek.github.io/django-cassandra-engine/) as my backend. My api works fine, but now I need add LDAP authentication.

I intend to use this package called [django-auth-ldap](https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/). From what I understand django-cassandra-engine doesn't support django-auth module on which django-auth-ldap rely on?

I have never worked with Cassandra before, and I consider myself a Django newbie.

Can someone be so kind and give me few hints how can I do this? Much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!